# My height and length doesn't save the value that i give

Tags: c, scanf

Every time i print height or length, the value is 0. It's like C doesn't save the value of xHeight, yHeight, xLength or yLength. I checked, and i don't think is a syntax problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

float xHeight,yHeight,xLength,yLength, height = 0.0, length = 0.0;

printf("Tell me the x and y: \n");
scanf(" %.2lf", &xHeight);
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%.2lf",&yHeight);
fflush(stdin);


height = xHeight - yHeight;;
printf("\n%.2lf",height);

printf("Now tell me another x and y: \n");
scanf(" %.2lf", &xLength);
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%.2lf",&yLength);
fflush(stdin);


length = xLength - yLength;
printf("\n%.2lf", length);

printf("\n==========================================\n");


printf("The perimeter of this rectangle is %.2lf", 2*(length+height));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/K39sYjq49). They are [your friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/).

Comment: If your compiler isn't warning you about those scanf calls, turn up warning options till it does. `-Wall -Wextra` is a good start for GCC and clang.

Comment: Also, always check the return value of scanf for errors before trying to use variables it sets. And `fflush(stdin);` is undefined.

Comment: The format specifier you are using for `scanf` is `%.2lf`, but should be `%.2f` for an ordinary `float`. `lf` is for `double`

Comment: Ether change `lf` to `f` in your `scanf` calls, or else change your floating point type to `double` (which I would do anyway - there's rarely a need to use `float`).

Comment: @Shawn, ... and on platforms where `fflush(stdin)` *is* defined, it may delete important input. Never use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%.2lf` is not a proper conversion specification for a `float`. There should be no `.2`, because `scanf` does not use a precision amount, and it should be `f` not `lf`, because `f` is for a pointer to a `float` while `lf` is for a pointer to a `double`.

You also do not need a space character before `%f` in `scanf`; the `%f` conversion automatically skips initial white space.

Use `scanf("%f", &xHeight);` and similarly in the other `scanf` calls.